# adding and sorting items into a singly linked list

Tags: c#, class

I am learning how to work with classes. I have made two classes and one is a list of cars. However, I need to modify the add function so that it will add cars sorted by price. The problem I am having is that it will send the cheapest car to the beginning but kill the rest of the list. Here is my code for the add...

```
public void add_car(the_cars new_car)
        {// Method to add cars to list
            if (count == 0)
            {// If this is the first car 
                first = new_car;
                last = new_car;
                count = 1;
            }
            else
            {// If it is not the first car
                if (new_car.getPrice() < first.getPrice())
                {// If price of new car is lower than first car
                    last = first;
                    first = new_car; // new car becomes first car
                }
                else
                {
                    while (new_car.getPrice() > last.getPrice() || last.next != null)
                    {
                        last.next = new_car; // Null value now equal to car
                        last = new_car;
                    }
                }


                count++;
```

Comment: Please edit your title to describe your question.

Comment: Your code is currently *very* unidiomatic in terms of C#. Learn about .NET naming conventions and properties. Additionally, we really don't know enough about the rest of your code...

Comment: The C# way to handle this would be to use the SortedList class that is part of the .Net Framework.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx  I understand that you're still learning how to work with classes, and that's awesome.  In the case above, your list_of_cars is actually a LinkedList, and when you reassign the head of the list you're forgetting to reassign the pointer NEXT to the rest of the list.

Comment: @MauriceReeves Actually the appropriate .NET class for this would be a `LinkedList`, this is a custom implementation of one.  It's also likely that it's being done for learning purposes, not in a business environment.  In a business environment it would be better to just use a `List` instead of having a `LinkedList`; it would be much more efficient.

Comment: No, I understand he's doing it for learning purposes, and that he's building a custom LinkedList, but I wanted to give him a pointer towards SortedList<T> because it's a library class, and something he should be aware of as he goes ahead.  The best scenario would be to build it using the parameters of the lesson, and then to build it a second time using the library classes to learn it both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have identified the cases correctly:

1. Is the list still empty?
2. Should the item be added at the beginning?
3. If not: after which item do we need to insert?

You implemented the first case alright.

The second case is wrong: Inserting in the beginning means to change the first element to `new_car`,  but `new_car.Next` needs to point to the previous first element, otherwise you lose the link.

The third case is also wrong: You need go towards the end of the list until either you've reached the last element (which is then the one you need to insert after) or until you find an element the successor of which has a greater price and insert after that.

The reason why I can put the `while` condition like that is that if `current != last` I can be sure that there's a `current.Next`, otherwise it would be `last` by definition. The reason I need a temporary iteration element is that if I modify `first` I lose the entry point to the list.

If have not tested the following code, but it should give you a clue and if it doesn't work, single-step debugging will help you.

```
public void add_car(the_cars new_car)
{// Method to add cars to list
    if (count == 0)
    {// If this is the first car 
        first = new_car;
        last = new_car;
        count = 1;
    }
    else
    {// If it is not the first car
        if (new_car.getPrice() < first.getPrice())
        {// If price of new car is lower than first car
            new_car.Next = first; // Insert the first car as the first element
            first = new_car;
        }
        else
        {
            // Create temporary iteration element
            the_cars current = first;

            // Find the car
            while (current != last && new_car.getPrice() >= current.Next.getPrice())
                current = current.Next;

            // Insert after the given element
            new_car.Next = current.Next;
            current.Next = new_car;

            // Also you may need to update last to match the new end
            if (current == last)
                last = new_car;
        }

        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To insert an item into a singly linked list you need to:

1. Change the previous nodes `next` (or `first` if it's the first item) to point to the new node.
2. Change the `next` of the new item to be what `next` used to be for the item just before your new item.  (You're not doing this in your code.)

If you have a doubly linked list (it doesn't appear you do) you also need to:

1. Change the current nodes `previous` to point to the node before you.
2. Change the next node's `previous` to point to you.

Note that these operations may need to be done in an order other than what I've specified them here.

Since you also have a `last` pointer, you need to check if that needs to be updated and update it.

Another problem that you have is that you're using `last` for adding anything after the first item.  You...don't want to be doing that.  You need to traverse the list, which will mean creating a new local variable to keep track of the current position.  As it is, your code is basically wiping out whatever was in `last`.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use the [LinkedList Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx), here is a sample implementation based on your scenario:

```
class CarList : LinkedList<Car>
{
    public void AddCar(Car newCar)
    {
        if (this.Count == 0)
        {
            AddFirst(newCar);
        }
        else
        {
            var referenceCar = Find(this.OrderByDescending(i => i.Price).Where(i => newCar.Price > i.Price).FirstOrDefault());
            if (referenceCar == null)
            {
                AddBefore(First, newCar);

            }
            else
            {
                this.AddAfter(referenceCar, newCar);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Car
{
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public Car(int price)
    {
        Price = price;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new CarList();
    list.AddCar(new Car(20000));
    list.AddCar(new Car(10000));
    list.AddCar(new Car(15000));

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Price {0}", item.Price);
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you sort the list with `OrderByDescending`. isn't the whole point of what you're trying to do that the list is always sorted. therefore you can omit that for efficiency